# removeAttr("style") doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this website: http://thc-cup.ucoz.com/
And to make the login form appear (by pressing the login button) I have to remove the style of the div which is hidden by default and of which I have no control.
I used this code:

```
<script>$("#baseLogForm").removeAttr("style");</script>
```

But it is not working, the div from where it should remove the style is still there.

Why it isn't working?
Thanks

Comment: Try `$("#baseLogForm").show()` or `$("#baseLogForm").css('display','block')`

Comment: you ned to wrap it in the `DOM REady` handler. `$(document).ready(function(){ ... })`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code isn't working because when it runs, your DOM isn't ready.

Try this way:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#baseLogForm").removeAttr("style");
});
```

or the shorter way...

```
$(function(){ //<< This is a "shortcut" to $(document).ready()
  $("#baseLogForm").removeAttr("style");
});
```

**BUT...**
You could simply do a `.show()` on this form, this will remove the `display: none` property in the style attribute of your form.

Answer (score 1):

You should simply use `.show()`

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#baseLogForm").show();
  });
```

**Note**: If you remove `style` attribute, if there are other css style those will be removed too.