# Remove size attribute from html input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the follow HTML code:

```
<input id="user_current_password" name="user[current_password]" size="20" type="password" style="display: none;">
```

I want to remove the size attribute. I already tried things like:

```
$("#user_current_password").removeAttr("size")
$("#user_current_password").attr("size","auto")
$("#user_current_password").attr("size","")
```

But it always give me the error: DOMException: Failed to set the 'size' property on 'HTMLInputElement': The value provided is 0, which is an invalid size.

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to just remove the size attribute or you want to increase or decrease the size depending on the size of input field.

Comment: @Alfaria, works for me!, which browser?

Comment: @alfaria, this is in document.ready right?  You waited unilt the DOM loaded right?

Comment: possible duplicate of [removeAttr("style") doesn't work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19890813/removeattrstyle-doesnt-work)

Comment: I am trying to remove the size attribute @Gaurav Kalyan

Comment: OneWay I am using google Chrome Version 39.0.2171.95

Comment: @DanielGimenez I tried that, inside document.read and didnt work. That thread is a similar situation, but the accepted answer does not solve the problem :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should solve it, using javascript only:

```
var a = document.getElementById('user_current_password');
a.setAttribute('size','auto'); // <<< set size as wished
```

Or, to remove it:

```
a.removeAttribute('size');
```

Please note to place this code within

```
window.onload = function() { /* code */ }
```

as the DOM has to be loaded in order to let the code find the Elements

Comment: Thanks :) I am going to test that. I am going to give you some feedback later :)